# Directing print output to a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Is there a way to save all of the print output to a txt file in python? Lets say I have the these two lines in my code and I want to save the print output to a file named `output.txt`.

```
print ("Hello stackoverflow!")
print ("I have a question.")
```

I want the `output.txt` file to to contain

```
Hello stackoverflow!
I have a question.
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Give `print` a `file` keyword argument, where the value of the argument is a file stream. The best practice is to open the file with the `open` function using a `with` block, which will ensure that the file gets closed for you at the end of the block:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
  print("Hello stackoverflow!", file=f)
  print("I have a question.", file=f)
```

From the [Python documentation about `print`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print):

> The `file` argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or `None`, `sys.stdout` will be used.

And [the documentation for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open):

> Open `file` and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an `OSError` is raised.

The `"a"` as the second argument of `open` means "append" - in other words, the existing contents of the file won't be overwritten. If you want the file to be overwritten instead at the beginning of the `with` block, use `"w"`.

---

The `with` block is useful because, otherwise, you'd need to remember to close the file yourself like this:

```
f = open("output.txt", "a")
print("Hello stackoverflow!", file=f)
print("I have a question.", file=f)
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. Once the first line of the code (first print) is executed, the corresponding file closes before actually executing the second print command. Right? Is there a way to print lots of stuff all together in the same file but making sure that the file closes before the second round of loop is executed? In other words, I would like to print some things in the same files for each round around the loop with closing file in between. Thanks,

Comment: @Allan, you should use a `with` statement to open the file. This creates a `file` object and keeps it open throughout an entire block, then closes it at the end. Check out the first example [in this article](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/). Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thank you, this works very nicely already. How could this be modified so that it's printed both in the file and the console; without evaluating the print statement only once so that time-consuming functions are only executed once?

Comment: @Julian please check the "print_both" function in this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206109/9492673 for printing both to console and in an output file

Comment: Only works for Python3

Answer (score 39):

You can redirect stdout into a file "output.txt":

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')
print ("Hello stackoverflow!")
print ("I have a question.")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this AND also show the text in the console?  So simultaneously print to console and to a file? I would like to be able to see all my progress print statements so I know where the program is in its execution, and the troubleshooting statements, but also have all of that dump to a text file.

Comment: @Korzak please check the "print_both" function in this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206109/9492673 for printing both to console and in an output file

Comment: This one is my favorite. I simply comment out/in one line to save the results on file after verifying them with the print command. No modification required to the print command!

Comment: To return to standard stdout print you can add `temp = sys.stdout` before `sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')`, and `sys.stdout = temp` after prints

Comment: @Korzak logging is a nice option for such a setup. The answer from gies0r could help here, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout) explanation is very clear

Answer (score 14):

Another method without having to update your Python code at all, would be to **redirect via the console**.

Basically, have your Python script `print()` as usual, then call the script from the command line and use command line redirection.  Like this:

```
$ python ./myscript.py > output.txt
```

Your `output.txt` file will now contain all output from your Python script.

**Edit:**
To address the comment; for Windows, change the forward-slash to a backslash.
(i.e. `.\myscript.py`)

Comment: This is Linux only. While I love linux, some people just use Windoze — and I'm perfectly fine with that as long as it doesn't affect me.

Answer (score 9):

Use the logging module

```
def init_logging():
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

    LOG_DIR = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'logs'
    if not os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
        os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(LOG_DIR, "g2"))
    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

    return rootLogger
```

Get the logger:

```
logger = init_logging()
```

And start logging/output(ing):

```
logger.debug('Hi! :)')
```

Answer (score 5):

Another Variation can be... Be sure to close the file afterwards

```
import sys
file = open('output.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = file

print("Hello stackoverflow!") 
print("I have a question.")

file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to import *sys* module. print whatever you want to write and want to save. In the *sys* module, we have *stdout*, which takes the output and stores it. Then close the *sys*.*stdout* . This will save the output.

```
import sys
# Save a reference to sys.stdout file object
stdout = sys.stdout

print("Hello stackoverflow!" \
      "I have a question.")

file = open("/home/scilab/Desktop/test.txt", "a")
sys.stdout = file
# main code ...

# Restore stdout to the sys.stdout file object you saved
# This prevents stdout from erroring out on a closed file     # object
sys.stdout = stdout
# Don't close stdout directly
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.4 we have [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
import contextlib

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    print("Hello stackoverflow!")
    print("I have a question.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose my input file is "input.txt" and output file is "output.txt".

Let's consider the input file has details to read:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Code:

```
import sys

sys.stdin = open("input", "r")
sys.stdout = open("output", "w")

print("Reading from input File : ")
n = int(input())
print("Value of n is :", n)

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(arr)
```

So this will read from input file and output will be displayed in output file.

For more details please see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inputoutput-external-file-cc-java-python-competitive-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Addding to the sys.stdout answer ; in order to make python go back to printing to the console instead of the file you would have to do:-

```
import sys
list = [10,20,30,40,50]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = f
    print(list)
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

PS.: All credit to https://www.datasciencelearner.com/get-python-output-in-text-file/ - that is where i found the information. (I made this an answer because i do not have the reputation to comment to the earlier answer.)

Edit: I edited the code to use a variable to store the old value of the `sys.stdout` and thereafter reassign it ; rather than using `sys.__stdout__` ; since the former is safer as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200790/13603594

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34846502)

Comment: This was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736177/6243352). `list` overwrites a builtin.