# Create output files from lines of loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list like this:

```
test_list = ['test1','test2','test3']
```

I want to create from each element of the array a separate txt file and write content to that like in below:

```
for test in test_list:
    print (test, outfile=testdir/test + '.txt')
```

Obviously this code doesn't work. I would like to know how can I do this?

Comment: `outfile` (which should be `file`) must be a Python's _file object_. __Please read the docs before asking questions and even attempting to write code.__ Quote from `help(print)`: "file:  a _file-like object_ (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout"

Comment: @ForceBru. I know. just wanted to show that what I need :). But I don't know how to create this

Comment: You don't know how to open files?

Comment: I don't know how to open multiple file. Because this was just example it can be 10000 files

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to keep 10000 files opened *at the same time*???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directing print output to a .txt file in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571560/directing-print-output-to-a-txt-file-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
test_list = ['test1','test2','test3']

for test in test_list:
    f = open('{}.txt'.format(test),'wb') #
    f.write(test)
    f.close()
```

for more visit : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: It won't on Python 3.x: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: yeah , but he has mentioned 2.7 also

Comment: Which was definitely a mistake as `print(stuff, arg=stuff)` works in Python 3.x only.

Comment: @ForceBru not necessarily, `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, however, the OP's code doesn't have this line. Tagging with both Python 3.x and Python 2.7 is strange anyway. 2 out of 3 answers here don't work in Python 3.x, so using both tags is clearly confusing.

Comment: @ForceBru Oh, I agree, the OP hasn't adequately specified their situation.

Comment: if he has accepted the answer then , it is definitely 2.7

Comment: @babygame0ver or it was the first one they saw (pattern works in 2.x and 3.x)

Answer (score 1):

```
test_list = ['test1','test2','test3']
for test in test_list:
   with open('{}.txt'.format(test),'w+') as f:
      f.write(test)
```

Comment: This is the correct method for Python 3.x as per the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @ForceBru it will if you change `wb` to `w+`. I was talking about the use of `with open` in terms of correct methods.

Answer (score -1):

I thing it will help you.

```
test_list = ['test1','test2','test3']
for l in test_list:
    with open('{}.txt'.format(l), 'a') as s:
         s.write(l)
```

If you want to write something you can use same as above.

Comment: Doesn't work as `s.write` returns an _integer_: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'close'`.

Comment: If you are using the `with open` syntax, you shouldn't need to call the `close()` method afterwards. See @user2614596 answer above

Comment: Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_list = ['test1','test2','test3']
>>> for l in test_list:
...     with open('{}.txt'.format(l), 'a') as s:
...          s.write(l)
... 
>>> 
>>> s
<closed file 'test3.txt', mode 'a' at 0x7f4558f700c0>
>>> 
not given any error please check once on version 2.7 V