# Using print with open=

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to print the below code to a file.
Looking through stack overflow I found the file=open code but it does not seem to be writing to a file.

PS. I haven't created the file yet

```
print("Average Grade " + str(average), "At least 70% " + 
      str(Grade1), "60% - 69% " + str(Grade2), "50% - 59% " +
      str(Grade3), "40% - 49% " + str(Grade4), "Less than 40% " + 
      str(Grade5), "Highest Grade " +
      str(max_grade), "Student Name:" + str(student_name), sep="\n", 
      file=open("results.txt", 'a'))
```

Comment: Printing a string does not imply that it is written to a file. Use ``file.write(yourstring)`` to actually do it. Also, use a context manager if possible.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm still fairly new to this

Comment: This is where I found the code . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571560/directing-print-output-to-a-txt-file-in-python-3

Comment: Using the `file=...` argument in `print` should work. Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve] so readers can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your code works for me (python 3.6).  Are you looking at `results.txt` in the right directory, and after the program has run?

Comment: @DaveIrwin the code is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
file = open("Here you put your path to a file, but replace '\' with '\\'", 'w+')
# That opened your file in 'write' mode, and '+' means that if it does not 
# exist, one will be created
file.write("Average Grade " + str(average), "At least 70% " + 
str(Grade1), "60% - 69% " + str(Grade2), "50% - 59% " +
str(Grade3), "40% - 49% " + str(Grade4), "Less than 40% " + 
str(Grade5), "Highest Grade " +
str(max_grade), "Student Name:" + str(student_name))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, we don't normally do this using print statements. Consider the following alternative. Using a "context manager" allows you to write more than one line, and also helps avoid certain problems if the program throws an error while writing to the file.

```
with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
    line = "Average Grade " + str(average), "At least 70% " + str(Grade1), "60% - 69% " + str(Grade2), "50% - 59% " + str(Grade3), "40% - 49% " + str(Grade4), "Less than 40% " + str(Grade5), "Highest Grade " + str(max_grade), "Student Name:" + str(student_name)
    f.write(line)
```

Incidentally, if you are doing this interactively, you may not see data written to the file instantly- this can be a real point of confusion when using a terminal instead of running a script! What happens is that python writes data to the file in large blocks, rather than asking the hard drive to do work every time `f.write` is called. `flush`ing the output buffer tells python to write the data immediately- eg `f.flush()`.

The print statement actually does have a `flush` argument, which may be highly relevant for that reason. Still, I would recommend using a `with` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("results.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write("Average Grade " + str(average), "At least 70% " + 
    str(Grade1), "60% - 69% " + str(Grade2), "50% - 59% " +
    str(Grade3), "40% - 49% " + str(Grade4), "Less than 40% " + 
    str(Grade5), "Highest Grade " +
    str(max_grade), "Student Name:" + str(student_name))
```

note that the 'a' option in open is for appending. You can also use 'w' for write.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I opened file then used file= at end of print.

```
newFile = open("results.txt", 'w')

print("Average Grade " + str(average), "At least 70% " + str(Grade1), "60% - 69% " + str(Grade2), "50% - 59% " +
  str(Grade3), "40% - 49% " + str(Grade4), "Less than 40% " + str(Grade5), "Highest Grade " +
  str(max_grade), "Student Name:" + str(student_name), sep="\n", file=newFile)

newFile.close()
```